# String containing Apostrophe Character U+2019 converts to more characters when passed to PreparedStatement object

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a java String that has the apostrophe character `‘` (which is different from `'`). 
The length of my string containing that character is 35 and can be verified using the `.length` method.

However, when passing this string containing the `‘` to a PreparedStatement object using the `setString` method `pstmt.setString(1, description);`, the length of the string gets translated to a 37 character string which can be seen from the following error message I am getting:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: value too large 
for column "DESCRIPTION" (actual: 37, maximum: 35)
```

What would be the most elegant way to handle this problem?

Comment: Incidentally, with Oracle 9 and above, you can define your character field using `varchar(35 char)` (or something like that), which will reserve enough space for the encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the length of your String before inserting it in DB, you have to convert it to the charset used by your DB. It can be done with

```
 new String(string, charset);
```

for instance

```
 System.out.println("‘".length()); 
 // displays 1
 System.out.println(new String("‘".getBytes(), "UTF-16").length()); 
 // displays 2
 System.out.println(new String("‘".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1").length()); 
 // displays 3
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: This is the right idea, but the wrong approach. The call to `getBytes()` will use the default encoding, which might be anything. Instead, you should be using `"‘".getBytes("UTF-8").length`, because those are the actual bytes that go into the database.

Comment: (assuming that the database is configured for UTF-8)